# Facebook sends a blank signed request for secured app when accessed by http

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-apps

I have an app that only runs on https. So my Pag Tab URL and Secured Page Tab URL have the same https url.

I have noticed that I get a blank signed request for users who are using Facebook on http.

Is there a way by which I can get the users to see my secured content even when they are accessing facebook from http?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook says that this configuration is not supported by design. Apps *must* be available via *both* HTTP and HTTPS.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/210713629051920/

> Unfortunately it is necessary you always provide a HTTP alternative
>   for FB users who want to visit your App under HTTP. In your specific
>   case, in your http endpoint you will be able to display an specific
>   message to these users encouraging them to visit the HTTPS version of
>   your App.